# Shape outlines show through on other shapes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke

I started getting a weird issue where outlines of shapes that are behind other shapes are showing through. I tested if it happens in a new document and it doesn't, so it must be something strange going on in my current document, but I don't know what it is.

[image]

Comment: I would start by checking what's enabled in your View settings.  Maybe you have something turned on there.  I can't seem to replicate this, myself.